# Reading a file into memory C++: Is there a getline() for std::strings

Tags: c++, fileinputstream, stringstream, string-parsing, stdstring

I was asked to update my code that reads in a text file and parses it for specific strings.

Basically instead of opening the text file every time, I want to read the text file into memory and have it for the duration of the object.

I was wondering if there was a similar function to getline() I could use for a std::string like i can for a std::ifstream.

I realize I could just use a while/for loop but I am curious if there is some other way. Here is what I am currently doing:

file.txt: (\n represents a newline )

[file.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhJOR.jpg)

My Code:

```
ifstream file("/tmp/file.txt");
int argIndex = 0;
std::string arg,line,substring,whatIneed1,whatIneed2;
if(file)
{
    while(std::getline(file,line))
    {
        if(line.find("3421",0) != string::npos)
        {
            std::getline(file,line);
            std::getline(file,line);
            std::stringstream ss1(line);
            std::getline(file,line);
            std::stringstream ss2(line);
            while( ss1 >> arg)
            {
                if( argIndex==0)
                {
                    whatIneed1 = arg;
                }
                argIndex++;
             }
             argIndex=0;
            while( ss2 >> arg)
            {
                if( argIndex==0)
                {
                    whatIneed2 = arg;
                }
                argIndex++;
             }
             argIndex=0;
         }
     }
 }
```

Where at the end whatIneed1=="whatIneed1" and whatIneed2=="whatIneed2".

Is there a way to do this with storing file.txt in a std::string instead of a std::ifstream asnd using a function like getline()? I like getline() because it makes getting the next line of the file that much easier.

Comment: search for 'slurp'

Comment: No. `std::string` knows nothing of files. The only way to read from a file in C++ is to use one of file streams. Please note, there are ways to read from files outside of C++, but those ways are unlikely to support `std::string`. It is also unclear what is your end goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've already read the data into a string, you can use `std::stringstream` to turn it into a file-like object compatible with `getline`.

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss.str(file_contents_str);
std::string line;
while (std::getline(ss, line))
    // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than grab a line then try to extract one thing from it, why not extract the one thing, then discard the line?

```
std::string whatIneed1, whatIneed2, ignored;
if(ifstream file("/tmp/file.txt"))
{
    for(std::string line; std::getline(file,line);)
    {
        if(line.find("3421",0) != string::npos)
        {
            std::getline(file, ignored);
            file >> whatIneed1;
            std::getline(file, ignored);
            file >> whatIneed2;
            std::getline(file, ignored);
        }
    }
}
```